# Static initialization in C++ mixed with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, initialization

I have an iPhone game, a port from C++ on other platforms.  So the user interface is coded in Obj-C, but the core logic of the program is in several C++ files.  Some of those C++ files have numerous global variables with initializers, at the top.

Surprise!  Debugging would suggest that the initialization never took place.  As if Obj-C linkage doesn't know to call the C++ static initialization chain.  Anybody know a fix for this?  A way to manually force those initialization routines to get called?

Ken

Comment: Have you tried converting to Obj-C++, i.e. renaming all your `.m` source files to `.mm`?

Comment: Dang shame that C++ doesn't have a standard way to call its program initializers from external code, like Ada does. For that matter, its a shame C++ doesn't have a standard way to control initialization order, or anything else about initialization, like Ada does.

Comment: @T.E.D: Actually the initialization order is well defined in C++ (even for global s). The problem you are trying to elude too is order of initialization across compilation units, but that should not be a problem as global s in different compilation units should not be talking to each other (that's a design problem not a language problem). We can see that Ada got everything correct by the popularity of the language :-p

Comment: C++ support was incomplete and buggy in older versions of `clang`. It's possible this is causing a problem. Other than that, I would poke at the object files and executable to see whether the static initialization code is even present. Is there a `.ctor` section or something similar? What functions are listed in there?

Comment: @Martin York - Actually a better indication of that is by how much of Ada they are adding to C++ 201x. Worse-Is-Better design triumphs again. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Static initialization with global variable is **generally** considered harmful. The order of initialization is implementation dependent. Also it doesn't work well with Obj-C compilers.

Use [Construct On First Use Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use) instead.

See also this site: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15